# Asp.net WebApi Entity Framework Controller with local state

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I try to create SPA using angularjs that allow change data in EF context without call saveChanges() and then save(call saveChanges()) or cancel changes.

MyController.cs

```
public class MyController : ApiController
    {
        private Oralce_dbContainer _db = new Oralce_dbContainer();

        [Route("Items/{ParentId:int?}")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetItems(int? ParentId)
        {

            var Parent = await _db.parents.FindAsync(ParentId);
            var items = Parent.Item.ToList();
            return Ok(items);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Delete")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(Item item)
        {                
            var i = await _db.Item.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.id == item.id);
            _db.Item.Remove(i);
            return Ok(true);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }    
    }
```

I get items then post delete and get items again I get all items with deleted item. How can i save EF context beetwen calling controller actions?

Answer (score 0):

Live Cycle of your Oralce_dbContainer is per request, so after calling Delete api and response _db object disposed. You must call SaveChange after delete in same request.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(Item item)
{                
    var i = await _db.Item.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.id == item.id);
    _db.Item.Remove(i);
    _db.SaveChanges();

    return Ok(true);
}
```